# Select Query to Select Unique Combos

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I am using MS Access----

In the database I have a table (let's call it Table) with 4 fields (let's call the F1, F2, F3, and F4).

Can anyone help me with a SQL code that would select unique combinations of F2,F3,and F4?

Comment: I don't see how order would relate to fields.

Comment: F2 + F3 + F4 is not the same as F3 + F2 + F4. Given that it doesn't matter, you can just do a 'distinct'

Comment: fields are intrinsically ordered since they're on a table I assume.

Comment: yes, but you can choose to pay attention to the order (if you wish). If not, as I stated, just do a 'distinct'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need the [DISTINCT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/all-distinct-distinctrow-top-predicates-HA001231351.aspx) keyword:

Basically:

```
SELECT DISTINCT F2, F3, F4 FROM Table;
```